# Can't bind to 'rxLetSuspenseTrigger' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'

Tags: angular, rx-angular

I have a `search` component that should show content and a loader depending on whether a stream has emitted. The suspense state should be triggered by `query$`.

```html
<section id="search-modal">
    <ng-container
        <!-- I tried with the suspenseTrg like this -->
        *rxLet="content$; let contents; suspense: suspense; suspenseTrg: query$"
        <!-- and like this -->
        [rxLetSuspenseTrigger]="query$"
    >
      <div class="content" [style]="size$ | async">
          <img
              *ngFor="let content of contents"
              smartImg
              [src]="content.poster"
              [resolution]="2"
              [viewMovie]="{ id: content.tmdb_id, type: content.type_ }"
        />
      </div>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #suspense class="container center">
        <div class="loader center"></div>
    </ng-template>
</section>
```

Using version:

```json
"@rx-angular/template": "^16.1.1",
```

In app.module.ts

```js
...
import { RxFor } from '@rx-angular/template/for';
import { RxLet } from '@rx-angular/template/let';
import { RxPush } from '@rx-angular/template/push';
import { RxUnpatch } from '@rx-angular/template/unpatch';
...
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...,
    RxLet,
    RxFor,
    RxPush,
    RxUnpatch,
    ...
  ]
})
```

VSCode does not recognise `[rxLetSuspenseTrigger]="query$"` and does not compile (with error `Can't bind to 'rxLetSuspenseTrigger' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'`) .
VSCode accepts `*rxLet="content$; let contents; suspense: suspense; suspenseTrg: query$"` but then the browser throws the same error. 
Am I missing some imports?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the docs for the context Triggers are not updated [RxLet docs](https://www.rx-angular.io/docs/template/api/rx-let-directive)

The context property names have been renamed to have the suffix Trigger instead of Trg (in the let.directive.d.ts file)

```html
*rxLet="content$; let contents; suspense: suspense; suspenseTrigger: query$"
```